# extracting one facet from a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I have 2 plots, each showing a different type of data (vaccines, and illnesses), and I would like to extract segments of these plots to generate a plot per subject, that has both the vaccines and the illnesses, **colored according to the original plot**.

```
vac
  subject age  vaccine
1     E11 1.0 DTaP-IPV
2     E11 3.0 DTaP-IPV
3     E22 1.0 DTaP-IPV
4     E22 2.0     Rota
5     E22 3.0 DTaP-IPV
6     E22 3.3     Rota

ill
  subject age       illness
1     E11 0.5 ear infection
2     E11 2.0 ear infection
3     E22 0.8         fever
4     E22 1.2         fever
5     E22 3.0 ear infection

ggplot(vac,aes(x=age,y=subject,color=vaccine))+geom_point(size=5) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1",drop = FALSE)+facet_grid(subject~.)
```

[image: OnlyVaccines]

```
ggplot(ill,aes(x=age,y=subject,color=illness))+geom_point(size=5) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Set3",drop = FALSE)+facet_grid(subject~.)
```

[image: OnlyFever]

Now, I would like to have one figure for E11, that has one row of vaccines (colored in Set1 colors), and one row of illnesses (colored in Set3 colors), and the same for E22.

I have many data types, and ~40 subjects, so of course, I would like this done automatically, and not via illustrator, etc.

I think gtable is the way to go, but not sure how to extract one facet.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Do did you want a legend at all? Because that's going to be another problem if you do.

Comment: I can do without a legend. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution that might help you in the right direction.  Give it a shot.

```
require(reshape2)
require(plyr)
dat <- melt(join(vac, ill, type="full"), id.vars = c("subject", "age"), na.rm=TRUE)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=age,y=variable, color=value))+geom_point(size=5) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1",drop = FALSE)+facet_grid(subject~.)
```

Comment: Thanks Leandro, but the problem here that I can only give one color scheme for all points. If I generate the plots separately, I can supply a different color scheme for each variable. thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure hot to approach this aside from using your individual color schemes to form a "master" color scheme that you then apply to the whole plot(s).  But in order to do that you would need to understand how many factors there are for each data type.  If you need help on this I can provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

The code below combines `vac` and `ill` in a single data frame (adding a new variable `type` to distinguish vaccines from illnesses), which will allow us to plot both illnesses and vaccines in a single call to `ggplot`. The code is a bit clunky, but I'm hoping it gets you closer to what you're looking for.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gridExtra)

# Combine data frames vac and ill by adding a new column 
# called "type" and changing name of the third column to "condition"
vac$type = "Vaccine"
names(vac)[3] = "condition"

ill$type = "Illness"
names(ill)[3] = "condition"

dat = rbind(vac, ill)

# Convert condition to a factor to get the levels ordered properly
dat$condition = factor(dat$condition, 
                       levels=c(unique(dat$condition[dat$type=="Vaccine"]), 
                                unique(dat$condition[dat$type=="Illness"])))

dat
   subject age     condition    type
1      E11 0.5 ear infection Illness
2      E11 2.0 ear infection Illness
3      E22 3.0 ear infection Illness
4      E22 0.8         fever Illness
5      E22 1.2         fever Illness
6      E11 1.0      DTaP-IPV Vaccine
7      E11 3.0      DTaP-IPV Vaccine
8      E22 1.0      DTaP-IPV Vaccine
9      E22 3.0      DTaP-IPV Vaccine
10     E22 2.0          Rota Vaccine
11     E22 3.3          Rota Vaccine
```

Now we generate one graph per subject, place each graph in a list, and then save all the graphs in a single PDF file. The `ggplot` code works as follows:

- Facet by `subject` so that we get a strip with the subject's ID.
- Facet by `type`, so that we get separate graphs for illness and vaccine.
- Use the color palette created below to get the colors we want

`pal1 = c(brewer.pal(n=3, name="Set1")[1:2], 
            brewer.pal(n=3, name="Set3")[1:2])`

```
p = list() 
for (i in unique(dat$subject)) { 
  p[[i]] = ggplot(dat[dat$subject==i,], 
                  aes(x=age, y=condition, colour=condition)) +
    geom_point(size=5) + 
    scale_color_manual(values=pal1, drop=FALSE) + 
    facet_grid(type ~ subject, scale="free") + ylab("") + 
   guides(colour=FALSE) 
}

pdf("plots.pdf", 9,5)
do.call("grid.arrange", p)  
dev.off()
```

And here's the graph:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the facets you created in your question, you have empty rows for the subjects not in the facet. Having ~40 subjects this will create facets with one filled row and 39 empty rows, which is probably not what you want.

An alternative solution:

```
# merging the dataframes together
dat <- merge(vac, ill, by=c("subject","age"), all=TRUE, sort=TRUE)

# creating the plot
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=dat[!is.na(dat$vaccine),], aes(x=age, y=subject, fill=vaccine), size=10, shape=22) +
  geom_point(data=dat[!is.na(dat$illness),], aes(x=age, y=subject, color=illness), size=7, shape=17) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Set2") +
  theme_bw()
```

which gives:
[image]